# Properties of subGaussian random variables

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics

Let $Y$ be a random variable and let $X$ be a subGaussian random variable.

Is it true that if $E( \exp tY ) \leq E( \exp tX ) $ then $Y$ is subGaussian?

Answer (score 6):

WLG, assume that $X$ has mean $0$. We say $X$ is sub-Gaussian if there exists $\sigma>0$ such that 
$$E(\exp(tX)) \leq \exp \left(\frac{t^2\sigma^2}{2}\right).$$

So, if $E( \exp tY ) \leq E( \exp tX )$, then $E( \exp tY ) \leq \exp \left(\frac{t^2\sigma^2}{2}\right).$

Hence $Y$ is sub-Gaussian (using definition).